# How do I write a pipe filter in Rust?

Tags: rust

A pipe filter is a program to drop between unix pipes: `source | filter | sink`. I'd like for it to do as little buffering as possible, and to process things as they come, rather than reading everything and only starting to process data on `EOF`.

I'm very new to Rust, and this is a learning project. The whole pipe filter thing is meant to be scaffolding for me to play with string processing on the commandline, and arises from the need to get unsanitized JSON from conky and cleaning it up for i3bar.

Here's what I have. It doesn't do any processing, and should just dump stdin to stdout.

I'm unsure whether `read_line()` will block until a newline character is found, and how to check whether it returned something I can work with. I know it returns an `IoResult`, but I haven't been able to find out how to do a match against it. It seems the `try!` macro is used in this context, but I'm not sure how.

When it reaches the `sleep()` call, it appears to sleep indefinitely.

```
use std::io;
use std::io::timer;
use std::time::Duration;

fn main() {
    let mut reader = io::stdin();
    let interval = Duration::milliseconds(1000);
    let mut line;

    loop {
        line = reader.read_line();
        print!("{}", line);

        timer::sleep(interval);
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll ultimately have to choose what you mean by "efficient". If you do "as little buffering as possible", then you will use less memory, but perhaps more CPU or user time. You can usually be efficient in one area and not in another.

Comment: Your code seems to echo input to output well enough (except `line` is a Result so the output is wrapped in `Ok` or `Err`)

Comment: Bad wording on my part. With 'efficient' I meant 'doesn't buffer forever', rather than resource efficient.

Comment: @mkaito would you please kindly share reference URLs to where you got your other questions answered? ideally, maybe even a demonstration of your solution?

Comment: Dude that was 6 years ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've crammed 3 (or more) separate questions in here...

> I'm unsure whether read_line() will block until a newline character is found.

The [docs for read_line](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Buffer.html#method.read_line) aren't specific on this point, but I think it will not return until it was able to read a full line (or has an error).

> How to check whether it returned something I can work with. I know it returns an IoResult, but I haven't been able to find out how to do a match against it.

IoResult is basically another name for a [`Result`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html), which is a normal `enum`. You can match it like so:

```
match io_method() {
  Ok(_) => thing_1(),
  Err(_) => thing_2(),
}
```

Usually you'd do something useful with the values in `Ok` and `Err`.

> It seems the try! macro is used in this context, but I'm not sure how.

The [docs for `try!`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.try!.html) show how it is implemented. It's an easy way to say "if an error occurred, return that error to my caller". At some point, you have to decide what do do with the error, but `try!` says deal with it later.

Comment: If I understand things correctly, there's an implicit buffer on stdin, and I can just read from it a line at a time, without having to wait for it to receive an EOL, correct? Would I need to do anything to prevent stdout buffering when printing?

Comment: That sounds like a separate question.

Comment: Roger that. Posting a new question.